# Xcode WebView. How to add close/done button when pdf file is opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have a small app for iOS that uses WebView.

When I open a PDF file from WebView, I can't close the window or go back. How to add the button back or close, when the PDF file is opened.

[URL to PDF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdPO6.jpg)   |   [PDF file is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyF7h.jpg)

```
#import "HomeController.h"

@interface HomeController ()

@end

@implementation HomeController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.mysite.com"];
     NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
     [myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
}

@end
```

**EDITED**

```
    //I create global BOOL isPdf in header file

    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isPdf;

    //I make request in view did load

myWebView.delegate=self;

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.mysite.com"];
_isPdf = [myURL.lastPathComponent isEqualToString:@".pdf"];
 NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
 [myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];

 NSLog(@"Run WebView with the URL");

    //And then in my webview delegate method

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
        if (_isPdf) {
            UIBarButtonItem *backButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=backButton;
            NSLog(@"Show back button %i", _isPdf);
        }else{
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;
            NSLog(@"Not show back button %i", _isPdf);
        }
    }

// Add backButtonPressed method

-(void)backButtonPressed{
    //update the method according to your need
    if (myWebView.canGoBack) {
        [myWebView goBack];
    }else{
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do three things

1. Confirm the webview delegates
2. Implement webview delegate webviewDidFinishLoad methods
3. Create a methods for the button action

First confirm the webview delegate in view did load

```
webview.delegate=self //(don't forgot to add the webview protocol <UIWebviewDelegate>)
```

Second implement webview delegate

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
  if (webView.canGoBack) {
      UIBarButtonItem *backButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=backButton;
  }else{
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;
  }
}
```

Third add backButtonPressed method

```
-(void)backButtonPressed{
   //update the method according to your need
   if (webview.canGoBack) {
       [webview goBack]
   }else{
       [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
   }
}
```

**Edit**

if you want to show button only on pdf then when you make request like your doing in view did load create a global BOOL isPdf and set it when you load request like

```
 NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.mysite.com"];
 isPdf=[myURL.lastPathComponent isEqualToString:@".pdf"];
```

and then in your webview delegate method :-

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
  if (isPdf) {
      UIBarButtonItem *backButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=backButton;
  }else{
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great! But I need a back button that shows only if the PDF file is open. How to make the right condition for this?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work for me. isPdf always returns 0. What did I miss? I updated my question

Comment: your url.. "http://test.mysite.com" is not a pdf right? try something like this "https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.pdf"

Comment: If I use a direct link to the PDF file, then I also get 0